# Android bitmap coordinate wierdness

Tags: android

I am trying to develop a custom image display application for android. So far I am able to load a bitmap and display it on the screen. I want to center the users view on the center of the image. To do this, I have been using

```
Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(...)
float offsetX = (androidScreenHeight - bitmapFactoryOptions.outHeight) / 2
canvas.drawBitmap(bmp, offsetX, 0, myPaint)
```

to render it. androidScreenHeight is correct as far as I can tell. I am using a samsung note which has 1280x800 screen which is the value I am getting for that. My image is 1920 pixels wide, so the offset on each side should be 560, with 800 in the middle for the actual screen. See this picture:

!https://i.stack.imgur.com/BT4Zu.jpg

The value of offsetX is correct at 560. So I know at least that part is working correctly. But instead of the above, what I am getting is this:

!https://i.stack.imgur.com/Aznlb.jpg

(these are not the actual image)

I am not sure what is going on. Are `pixels` treated differently somehow on my android device than on my computer? I understand that each pixel will take up a different size on each since the dpi is different. but an offset of 560 pixels should give the same offset on each screen, regardless of the size of the individual pixels. Any ideas what is going on here?

Comment: What drawable folder is your resource in? BitmapFactory will perform scaling between that folder's dpi (assuming you have one) and the device dpi. Putting the bitmap in 'drawable-nodpi' will disable the autoscaling but be careful that you really want to do this (cos autoscaling is usually useful and desirable).

Comment: Awesome! That fixed it, thank you! Is it possible to accept your answer or something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Promoting my comment to proper answer)

BitmapFactory will perform scaling between that folder's dpi (assuming you have one) and the device dpi. Putting the bitmap in 'drawable-nodpi' will disable the autoscaling but be careful that you really want to do this (cos autoscaling is usually useful and desirable).